# what is the correct way to alias a binary in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: software-installation

If I want to alias a executable file in `/usr/local/bin` , Is there a *correct* way to make such an alias? and how can I make one? Softlink? Hardlink? Something else?
For example, when I

```
apt-get install vim;
```

Aptitude will alias `/usr/local/bin/vi` as `/usr/local/bin/vim` (if I recall correctly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, there is a way to "alias" default apps. What you are encountering with `sudo apt-get install vim` is [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).

Basically , that system has list of default apps in `/etc/alternatives/` folder, which are symlinks to whatever default app you have. Before installing `vim` you have `vim.tiny`, so `vi` gets symlinked to `/etc/alternatives/vi` , which then is symlinked to `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`. Once you get the actual `vim`, those symlinks all get updated to ultimately point to `vim`.

Of course there is manual way through `sudo update-alternatives --config vi`. And there of course is nothing stopping you from creating your own symlinks there. However for programs that aren't going to have many many different implementations, like `screen` for example, you could just leave them alone. Provided that `/usr/bin` is in your `$PATH` variable (which it should always be), you can just type in `myappname` and it will run.

Comment: A good overview of the defaults mechanism.

Comment: interesting. a symlink it is, then. in fustration over debian's pastebinit , i wrote a clone using fedora's pastebin. now i want pastebinit to be an alias for pastebinit.php -- https://github.com/divinity76/pastebinit_php

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, *don't hard link*.

Hard links lead to confusing issues when, for example, you try to delete the file, because if you don't remember to delete it *twice* it's still there.

In the case of a program, this can lead to hard-to-debug behaviour, because the program may still be found at the hard link location. Depending on the content of the `PATH` environment variable, it could be executed under different circumstances to what is the case now.

Hard links are like `goto`s in programming: a hangover from an older time, now *considered harmful*.